# Parsing a char inside an if c#

Tags: c#, parsing

So I've got a character called oper, and i'm parsing it's value from a string. In this if statement I'm trying to check if oper's value is " ". I was told single quotes are needed for a char but I'm still not finding success. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectCalc
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double val1;
    double val2;
    char oper;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (oper = char.Parse('')) ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `' '` is a `char`; no need to parse it.

Comment: char.Parse takes a String not a character and use == for equality check not =

Comment: If your trying to see if your char is a space, in your code it is set to blank (no space)?

Comment: And don't put a semicolon at the end of your if statement.

Comment: First, you need to use `==` operator for equality check. Second, you don't need `char.Parse` you can simply do `if(oper ==' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. First, you do an assignment operation and not equality (single `=` vs `==`)
Secondly, if you have a string and want to check if one of his characters is space, you could do:

```
string myString = "This is a string";
foreach (var c in myString) {
if (c == ' ') // <=== Note the space between the single quotes 
 ... do something
}
```

Comment: With `System.Linq` you can do `myString.ToLower().Contains(' ')` as the test. Without the `System.Linq` extension: `myString.ToLower().IndexOf('s') != -1` Looping seems expensive here.

Comment: @JNevill why do you need ToLower for the first example?

Comment: Yea... totally don't here because we are looking for a space. Disregard that. heh.. a lowercase space.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Still new to C# and learning the proper syntax. Thanks Jonathan!

Comment: @JNevill I agree with your statement that Linq is better here, but I assumed this guy was novice and therefore didn't want to overwhelm with new information. Linq is preferred here for lots of reasons...

Comment: You're welcomed @Knotwood , if you think this resolves your issue, consider marking this as the answer. Good luck!